# how to move from sandbox to prod on twilio whatsapp

Tags: twilio, messaging, sandbox, whatsapp, production

Twilio Whatsapp - we have tested successfully on sandbox for our whatsapp messaging but how do we migrate it to prod. can someone help help how we can configure for prod.

Comment: you need to open a request with Twilio Support

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To move to production for WhatsApp you should follow [the steps outlined in this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/connect-number-business-profile).

At a high level the steps are:

1. Request access to enable your Twilio numbers for WhatsApp
2. Submit a WhatsApp Sender request in the Twilio console
3. Approve Twilio to message on your behalf in the Facebook Business Manager console
4. Submit your Facebook Business Manager account for Business Verification
5. (Twilio completes your WhatsApp Sender registration)

The tutorial has more details about [the steps needed to enable WhatsApp for production use with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/connect-number-business-profile).